# AppEngine + GitHub integration

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, github

I have a problem. My Github account is currently flagged and the files are not being uploaded after my commits. The trigger is OK but the files are not updated. How to solve this? Any way to manually upload the project? Is a vue js project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean uploading your project to Google App Engine manually, documentation for how to do so is available here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you have created a App Engine build trigger on commit. In order to manually use your trigger, please open the triggers page on the dashboard. Find your trigger and click "Run Trigger"[1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#testing_a_build_trigger